# Feature deactivation code behind in Sandbox solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Just a question to clarify my doubts here !

I created a Sandbox solution with Visual Studio 2010 for SharePoint 2010.

Solution contains just a list instance, and when the feature is deployed a list gets created on the site.

Now, I also wish to delete the list when the feature is deactivated.

For which I wrote below code in EventReceiver.cs.

`public override void FeatureDeactivating(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sitecollection"))
            {
                SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
                SPList list = web.Lists["listname"];
                list.Delete();
                list.Update();
                web.Update();
            }
        }`

While this does delete the list on feature deactivation, my question is,

How come this project is STILL a sandbox solution (no dll deployment to GAC) as it contains server-side & and a code behind file?

Thanks,

Tushar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandbox solutions can use server side code. The difference is that the code runs in separate windows service on server and not in w3wp process or owstimer. The cost is that you do not have access to all server side functionality (you cannot deploy timer jobs using sandbox solutions for example). You can read more about sandbox solutions [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721992%28v=office.14%29.aspx#understanding_solutions).